# How to remove extra spaces in between string, matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, for-loop

I have created a script to convert text to morsecode, and now I want to modify it to include a slash between words.So something like space slash space between morsecode words. I know my loop before the main loop is incorrect and I want to fix it to do as stated before I just really need help Thank You!!!:

```
...

Word=input('Please enter a word:','s');
  ...
             Code=MC_1;
    ...

    case ' '
         Code='/'
    otherwise 
         Valid=0;
end
if Valid
         fprintf('%s ',Code);
else
         disp('Input has invalid characters!')
         break
end
```

Comment: [This example translator](http://morsecode.scphillips.com/jtranslator.html) seems to format the Morse in the same way you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you want to write a loop to remove multiple spaces in between words, but the best way to remove white space in your particular problem would be to use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), specifically with [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html).  Regular expressions are used to search for particular patterns / substrings within a larger string.  In this case, what we are trying to find are substrings that consist of more than one whitespace.  `regexprep` finds substrings that match a pattern, and replaces them with another string.  In our case, you would search for any substrings within your string that contain at least one more whitespace characters, and replace them with a single whitespace character.  Also, I see that you've trimmed both leading and trailing whitespace for the string using [`strtrim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html), which is great.  Now, all you need to do is call`regexprep` like so:

```
Word = regexprep(Word, '\s+', ' ');
```

`\s+` is the regular expression for finding **at least one white space character**.  We then replace this with a single whitespace.  As such, supposing we had this string stored in `Word`:

```
Word = '   hello    how    are   you   ';
```

Doing a trim of leading and trailing whitespace, then calling `regexprep` in the way we talked about thus gives:

```
Word = strtrim(Word);
Word = regexprep(Word, '\s+', ' ')

Word =

hello how are you
```

As you can see, the leading and trailing white space was removed with `strtrim`, and the regular expression takes care of the rest of the spaces in between.

---

However, if you are dead set on using a loop, what you can do is use a `logical` variable which is set to `true` when we detect a white space, and then we use this variable and skip other white space characters **until** we hit a character that isn't a space.  We would then place our space, then `/`, then space, then continue.  In other words, do something like this:

```
Word = strtrim(Word); %// Remove leading and trailing whitespace
space_hit = false; %// Initialize space encountered flag
Word_noSpace = []; %// Will store our new string
for index=1:length(Word) %// For each character in our word
    if Word(index) == ' ' %// If we hit a space
       if space_hit %// Check to see if we have already hit a space
          continue; %// Continue if we have
       else
          Word_noSpace = [Word_noSpace ' ']; %// If not, add a space, then set the flag
          space_hit = true;
       end
    else
       space_hit = false; %// When we finally hit a non-space, set back to false
       Word_noSpace = [Word_noSpace Word(index)]; %// Keep appending characters
    end
end
Word = Word_noSpace; %// Replace to make compatible with the rest of your code

for Character = Word %// Your code begins here
   ...
   ...
```

What the above code does is that we have an empty string called `Word_noSpace` that will contain our word with no extra spaces, and those spaces replaced with a single whitespace.  The loop goes through each character, and should we encounter a space, we check to see if we have already encountered a space.  If we have, just continue on in the loop.  If we haven't, then concatenate a whitespace.  Once we finally hit a non-space character, we simply just add those characters that are not spaces to this new string.  The result will be a string with no extra spaces, and those are replaced with a single white space.

Running the above code after you trim the leading and trailing white space thus gives:

```
Word =

hello how are you
```